# How to encrypt HTML5 video source tag to avoid users to know the video path???

Tags: html, video

I want to restrict users to directly see the path of video in my site where i kept them..
Please revert asap.
Your helpfull answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is possible to do so.

Some solutions that come up in my mind:

- Encrypting video URL with **SHA1** or **MD5** and decrypt it back via JavaScript/jQuery.
- Using PHP or other dynamic url such as `http://example.com/video.php?id=1` (I think in the end they would be able to save it, depending on your implementation).

Comment: SHA1 and MD5 are no encryption functions but one-way hash functions. It is not feasible to revert the output back to the video URL in Javascript. "Real Encryption" like 3DES, AES etc might work but is probably not worth the effort as the Request can be seen in almost any current Browser - not matter what you do.